How to use knit_child with tempdir in Quarto?
I am using multiple levels of quarto tabsets to display variants of a graph programmatically (actually calling a recursive function on a nested list). Somehow this does not work with simple print. I found a solution via knit_child, calling
knitr::knit_child(
  text = c(
    '```{r}',
    glue('printout(l[["{name}"]])'),
    '```',
    ''
  ), 
  options = list(results = 'asis', echo = FALSE, ...),  # warning = FALSE, message = FALSE),
  envir = environment(), 
  quiet = TRUE
) %>%
  cat()   

this actually creates a figure, saves it and prints out something like figure/unnamed-chunk-X-1.pdf, which than gets interpreted to include the respective figure.
This works fine when rendering, however, when working interactively, I get an error that output.dir was not found in opts_knit. Ok, I can set that apriori with
knitr::opts_knit$set(output.dir = here::here()) 

However, that leaves a folder figure in my working directory. The problem is that if I set a different location, Quarto render does not find the pictures.
I would like to set
knitr::opts_knit$set(output.dir = tempdir()) 

and somehow point Quarto to that tempdir.
